# Material Design Lite - Where are checkboxes and lists?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, material-design, material-design-lite

Searching through the documentation here [getmdl.io](http://getmdl.io) and also through google

"site:getmdl.io checkbox"

I can't find the styling for lists and checkboxes. Am I missing something or is this basic input field like a checkbox missing?

Are these elements going to be patched in?

Comment: http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#toggles-section

Comment: Thx. Too bad google hasn't indexed the site already.

Comment: Would you mind pasting your comment as a regular answer, so that I can mark this thread as answerd?

Comment: link only answers aren't allowed on stackoverflow.

Comment: Also your answer only covers checkboxes and not lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkboxes can be found under the toggles section of the components tab http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#toggles-section

Comment: Thx. Somebody should probably make the site indexable from google or include a search function on the site.